# Workflow to compare the overlap in two images?

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing

I am going to have to apologize for the vagueness of this question in advance. I'm looking to help a friend who is trying to compare the overlap of flourescent nerves in two images.

The setup is as follows:
There is an image of nerves and background labeled in red, and the same image of nerves and background labeled in green. Some nerves only labeled with red, and some only labeled with green, and that's important. What we want to do is overlay the red image and green image, and then figure out which nerves label with both (where red and green overlap).

There is a continuum of intensity for both labels (so there're bright obvious lines of red and dim areas of red speckle, same for green).

I was thinking what you could do is set a threshold intensity for red, and re-plot the image with only those nerves that met that threshold intensity. You could do this for green as well. Then, with the outputs you could compare the proportion of overlapping nerves by measuring the percentage of nerve tissue in one output that is found in the other output.

It would be ideal to be able to generate an output image where overlapping areas could be coloured (e.g. blue). Then, we could take that output where all the overlaps are blue, and overlay it on the original red/green images to visually highlight nerves that overlap.

Alternatively (or in combination), you could convert the images to character strings, and then look for matching characters in the same positions in those character strings.

Either of these is far beyond my skill level ^_^;

If anyone thinks this is possible, has any suggestions for a better workflow to do it, or can point me in the direction of some good reading or a package to figure this out, it would be much appreciated.

Thanks for any help you can offer!

edit: This suggestion in Matlab answers the start of my question I think (how to measure which pixels exceed some threshold intensity). They convert to greyscale, and then look for intensity as pixels that are whitish. I'd then need to generate an output of just those pixels that meet that threshold intensity.

http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/86484-how-to-find-the-intensity-of-each-pixel-of-an-image

Comment: Provide example images.  You may need to solve the registation problem first, i.e. does everything line up correctly between images.

Comment: Here is an example of two images. You can see that the nerve branch that looks like an arrowhead overlaps in both red and green.

img1: http://img.photobucket.com/albums/v228/markh1822/M%20cluster%203%20tub_zpstyc93aoh.jpg

img2:
http://img.photobucket.com/albums/v228/markh1822/M%20cluster%203%20fmrf_zps5gk4o11q.jpg

Comment: The approach of taking thresholds of both images and then adding them together should work fine.  Alternatively, since you have one image in red and another in green, you could combine the colors to get a red green magenta image, magenta would be where the overlap is strong.

Comment: That was our plan to start. But unfortunately the green on red doesn't really look very distinguished. Playing around with transparencies, and different colours, it just doesn't quite leave the impression it needs to. Most of the time, the green swamps out the red.

Have a suggestion for code or where to look for code advice in image processing? Thanks for the response!

Comment: Follow the step in the link you provide to get threshold images.  Make a new image where all zeros is black, 1 red is red, 1 green is green, and both red and green you set to blue, the contrast should be ok.  Matlab's image processing toolbox is quite good and provides numerous examples to get you on the right track.

Comment: Is there a reason why you need to use Matlab to perform this task? [ImageJ](http://imagej.nih.gov/ij/docs/guide/index.html) (and [Fiji](http://fiji.sc/Fiji)) offer a lot of tools to do thresholding and overlap analysis, and don't need any programming skills to be used (while still offering to automate tasks via scripting if desired).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @JanEglinger suggests, there is no need to use (or pay for) Matlab, especially if your programming skills are limited.

I would suggest ImageMagick which is free and installed on most Linux distros and is also available for OSX and Windows from [here](http://imagemagick.org). The things you want to do can then be done from the commandline without compilers or development environments and steep learning curves.

Let's take your red image first, just using the commandline in the Terminal, we can look at the statistics like this:

```
identify -verbose red.jpg | more

Image: red.jpg
  Format: JPEG (Joint Photographic Experts Group JFIF format)
  Mime type: image/jpeg
  Class: DirectClass
  Geometry: 100x100+0+0
  Resolution: 72x72
  Print size: 1.38889x1.38889
  Units: PixelsPerInch
  Type: TrueColor
  Endianess: Undefined
  Colorspace: sRGB
  Depth: 8-bit
  Channel depth:
    red: 8-bit
    green: 8-bit
    blue: 8-bit
  Channel statistics:
    Pixels: 10000
    Red:
      min: 8 (0.0313725)
      max: 196 (0.768627)                                 <--- Good stuff in Red channel
      mean: 46.1708 (0.181062)
      standard deviation: 19.4835 (0.0764057)
    Green:
      min: 0 (0)
      max: 13 (0.0509804)                                 <--- Nothing much in Green channel
      mean: 3.912 (0.0153412)
      standard deviation: 1.69117 (0.00663204)
    Blue:
      min: 0 (0)
      max: 23 (0.0901961)                                 <--- Nothing much in Blue channel
      mean: 4.3983 (0.0172482)
      standard deviation: 2.88733 (0.0113229)
```

and see there is little information of any use outside the Red channel. So, we can then separate it into its 3 channels of Red, Green and Blue, and discard the Green and Blue channels like this:

```
convert red.jpg -separate -delete 1,2 justRed.jpg
```

which gives us this

[image]

The contrast is not very good though because it only ranges from 8-196 instead of 0-255 so we can normalize it to the full range and then threshold at 50% like this:

```
convert red.jpg -separate -delete 1,2 -normalize -threshold 50% r.jpg
```

which gives this:

[image]

If we now want to do the same for your green image, we would do this but delete the Red and Blue channels this time:

```
convert green.jpg -separate -delete 0,2 -normalize -threshold 50% g.jpg
```

giving this:

[image]

Finally, we take the separated, normalised, thresholded Red and Green and synthesize an empty Blue channel the same size and put them all together as the Red, Green and Blue channels of a new image:

```
convert r.jpg g.jpg -size 100x100 xc:black -combine result.jpg
```

That gives us this where we see in *Yellow* areas that were bright red and green.

[image]

The whole procedure is actually just 3 lines of typing in the Terminal:

```
convert red.jpg   -separate -delete 1,2 -normalize -threshold 50% r.jpg
convert green.jpg -separate -delete 0,2 -normalize -threshold 50% g.jpg
convert r.jpg g.jpg -size 100x100 xc:black -combine result.jpg
```

If you like the approach, you can vary the percentages, you could introduce noise reduction and also in fact do the whole lot in a single, more complicated command with no intermediate files. Anyway, I commend ImageMagick to you and even if you must use Matlab, maybe this example in ImageMagick will give you some pointers to a workflow.

Extra example... if you set the threshold lower for the Red channel, you will get more Red pixels in the output file, so if you change the Red threshold to say 30%, you will get this:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I have been playing around learning some `OpenCV` which is free and available for OSX, Linux and Windows. I thought it might add some interactivity for your question so I have implemented the exact same algorithm as I did in ImageMagick, but in my beginner's `OpenCV`. If anyone more experienced has any constructive guidelines for my code, I am all ears.

Anyway, it looks like this when running and you slide the threshold sliders around:

[image]

Here is the code:

```
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// NerveView.cpp
// Mark Setchell
//
// OpenCV program that takes two images as parameters, the first the red 
// fluorescent nerve image and the second which is the green image.
//
// The two images are resized, normalised and then displayed merged into a 
// single RGB image where the thresholds on red and green are controlled by
// sliders. Common areas therefore appear in yellow. Move either slider left
// to lower the threshold and therefore include more of that colour in the 
// combined output image, or move slider right to decrease amount of that
// colour.
//
// Run with:
//
// ./NerveView red.jpg green.jpg
//
// Compile with:
//
// g++ `pkg-config --cflags --libs opencv` NerveView.cpp -o NerveView
//
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"
#include "opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp"
#include <opencv/cv.h>
#include <opencv/highgui.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    // Temp workspace
    Mat tmp1,tmp2;

    // Image size
    Size size(640,480);

    // Create a window for controls
    namedWindow("Controls", CV_WINDOW_NORMAL);
    resizeWindow("Controls",640,100);

    // Create slider to change Red threshold
    int RedThreshold = 50;
    createTrackbar("Red Threshold Percentage", "Controls", &RedThreshold, 100);

    // Create slider to change Green threshold
    int GreenThreshold = 50;
    createTrackbar("Green Threshold Percentage", "Controls", &GreenThreshold, 100);

    // Create variables to store input images and load them
    Mat Red,Green;
    Mat planes[3];

    // Load red image, split, discard G & B, resize, normalize
    tmp1   = imread(argv[1], CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR);
    split(tmp1,planes);
    resize(planes[2],tmp1,size);
    normalize(tmp1,Red,0,255,NORM_MINMAX,CV_8UC1);

    // Load green image, split, discard R & B, resize, normalize
    tmp1   = imread(argv[2], CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR);
    split(tmp1,planes);
    resize(planes[1],tmp1,size);
    normalize(tmp1,Green,0,255,NORM_MINMAX,CV_8UC1);

    // Make empty Blue channel, same size
    Mat Blue=Mat::zeros(size,CV_8UC1);

    //Create window to display images
    cv::namedWindow("Image", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);

    // Create variable to store the processed image
    Mat img=Mat::zeros(640,480,CV_8UC3);

    while (true){

    // Get thresholds, apply to their channels and combine to form result
        threshold(Red,tmp1,(RedThreshold*255)/100,255,THRESH_BINARY);
        threshold(Green,tmp2,(GreenThreshold*255)/100,255,THRESH_BINARY);

        // Combine B, G and R channels into "img"
        vector<Mat> channels;
        channels.push_back(Blue);
        channels.push_back(tmp2);
        channels.push_back(tmp1);
        merge(channels,img);

        // Display result
        imshow("Image",img);

        // See if user pressed a key
        int key=cvWaitKey(50);
        if(key>=0)break;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

---

**Keywords**: nerve, nerves, fluorescence