# Gray scale images processing in C++

Tags: c++, image-processing, grayscale

How to read an image in C++ as a 2D array?  I need to create a C/C++ program that reads an image (all formats) as a 2D array to show pixel values (0-255), divide the image into blocks and apply different compression methods using pixels blocks (BTC, AMBTC, MMBTC) and saving the new image by hand without using already set libraries (must not use magic++)..
thanks in advance

Comment: Depends on the image format, the platform, your compiler, and many other things. Can you be a bit more specific?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Reading an image file in C/C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2076475/reading-an-image-file-in-c-c)

Comment: Take a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33780943/read-an-image-or-pdf-using-c-without-external-library

Comment: This is easiest... https://stackoverflow.com/a/33777883/2836621

Comment: Adrian Mole ..I use VS 2017 on Windows 10  .. no specific image format so if I could create a program that works on all formats it would be perfect, if not JPEG is a good start ..thank you

Comment: @HajarAlhalabi If you are comfortable with using `MFC` then the `CImage` class is your best pal: it can read all the standard formats (GIF, JPEG, TIFF, BMP, &c) and has member functions that make it *relatively* easy to get access to the raw pixel buffer. I can give you some sample code, if that's a direction you're happy to take.

Comment: @Close-Voter: OP is *not* looking for a library or off-site resource, *per se*. In fact they state: "without using already set libraries!"

Comment: @AdrianMole my next step is working on the interfaces of the program so the MFC would be perfect.. I would  appreciate it if you gave me a sample code..many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's some 'outline' code using MFC's `CImage` class that may help you. I've shown how to use the basic `Load` and `Save` options, and how to get a 'raw' array of pixel data (note: it's best to convert to 32-bit format, so you can be sure the `DWORD` pointer you get will *really* be to a `width X height` array - other BPP formats can give strange results):

First, load from file (`CImage` will know or guess the format from the file extension):

```cpp
CImage original;
original.Load("Yourfile.jpg"); // Use actual file path, obviously 

int pw = original.GetWidth(), ph = original.GetHeight(); // Dimensions
CImage working; // Use this to hold our 32-bit image
working.Create(pw, ph, 32);

// Next, copy image from original to working...
HDC hDC = working.GetDC();
original.BitBlt(hDC, 0, 0, SRCCOPY);
working.ReleaseDC();

// Get a DWORD pointer to the pixel data...
BITMAP bmp;
GetObject(working.operator HBITMAP(), sizeof(BITMAP), &bmp);
DWORD* pixbuf = static_cast<DWORD*>(bmp.bmBits);
// We can now access any pixel(x,y) data using: pixbuf[x + y * pw]
```

You now do all sorts of work on your image buffer, using the `pixbuf` array, as stated in the comment. For clarity: each `DWORD` (32-bit unsigned) in the buffer will be the `RGBA` data (where `A` is the 'alpha` channel - set to zero) *but* in *reversed* order; so, for each DWORD, the bytes will be 0xBBBBGGGGRRRR0000.

When you're done, you can save your modified image as follows:

```cpp
CImage savepic;
savepic.Create(pw, ph, 24); // Change 24 to whatever BPP you require
hDC = savepic.GetDC();
working.BitBlt(hDC, 0, 0, SRCCOPY); // Copies modified image to output
savepic.ReleaseDC();
savepic.Save("NewFile.jpg"); // CImage understand what format to use base on extension
```

Of course, in a real-world program, there are error checks that you will need to make (most `CImage` methods return a status indicator, and `GetLastError()` can be used), and you would probably be safer copying the 'pixbuf' data to a separate memory zone - but, hopefully, this brief outline will help you get started.

Feel free to ask for further clarification and/or explanation.